# How to report bugs for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: system-installation, bug-reporting

There is a cpu soft lockup when I am entering the installation gui when I am installing ubuntu 16.04, how to report bug for this?

Comment: The close vote for bug reporting points  to http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

You can install :

```
sudo apt-get install reportbug
```

*reportbug* first time create a *reportbug.conf* file in /etc

```
/etc/reportbug.conf

user@ubuntu01:reportbug
Please enter the name of the package in which you have found a problem.
> packagename
*** Welcome to reportbug.  Use ? for help at prompts. ***
Detected character set: UTF-8
Please change your locale if this is incorrect.

Using 'user name <user@ubuntu01>' as your from address.
```

Comment: Please add that to the topic in comments above.